# Javascript onclick if iframe exists, remove it and create new iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my javascript code to create `iframe`, how I can do it, `onclick` if `iframe` exists, remove it and create a new `iframe`?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function CreateIframe() {
    $(document).on('click', '.row a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this).attr('href');
        document.getElementById("avgames").style.display = "block";
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.frameBorder = 0;
        iframe.width = "75%";
        iframe.height = "620";
        iframe.maxHeight = "100%";
        iframe.id = "randomid";
        iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
        document.getElementById("avgames").appendChild(iframe);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may clear your `avgames` before append using `innerHTML = "";` like below. Its clear the existing `iframe` inside `avgames` . After that you `append` new one.

```
window.addEventListener('load', function CreateIframe() {
    $(document).on('click', '.row a', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        link = $(this).attr('href');
        document.getElementById(desireID).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("avgames").style.display = "block";
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.frameBorder = 0;
        iframe.width = "75%";
        iframe.height = "620";
        iframe.maxHeight = "100%";
        iframe.id = "randomid";
        iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
        document.getElementById("avgames").appendChild(iframe);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but with your code is not working `document.getElementById("avgames").style.display = "block";`

Comment: Code only clear `avgames`. Its not related to it's css.

Answer (score 1):

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function CreateIframe(){
 $(document).on('click', '.row a', function(e) {
  if($('body iframe').length){
   $('body iframe').remove();
   e.preventDefault();
   link =  $(this).attr('href');
   document.getElementById("avgames").style.display = "block";
   var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
   iframe.frameBorder=0;
   iframe.width="75%";
   iframe.height="620";
   iframe.maxHeight="100%";
   iframe.id="randomid";
   iframe.setAttribute("src", link);
   document.getElementById("avgames").appendChild(iframe);
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Always welcome... You can add else condition if required!

Answer (score 1):

My second Solution! :)

```
  $('iframe').not(this).remove();
```